# Page.IsPostback Occurring Multiple Times

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Page.ISpostback is getting multiple when first time page load it's   getting 5 times and when ever i click button or DropDownlist (!PAGE.ISPOSTBACK) loads multiple Time.I searched in Google Some one said because of Ajax it's getting multiple Times but he did not said how to solve.   Kindly help me to how to solve. Thanks in Advance

my code

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //gvbind();
            grid();
            year();
            Dropdown();
            Button1.Visible = false;`
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript in the aspx? Does it have any Ajax calls being made to the page or user control?

Comment: I did'nt understand the question fully and i am new to Dotnet. I am using ModalPopupExtender Ajax kit for Popup of Webform1.aspx from webform2.aspx and Java script for numeric validation for Texbox.

Comment: And page multiple times redirect into to Identity.cs,identityconfig.cs pages .